# How to determine if null value is System.String or System.Nullable<int>

Tags: c#

I have a simple method the I pass a property in as `arg`. I then try to determine what format to return either a string, int or decimal. Here is the method.

```
    protected T GetValue<T>(T arg, List<string> item, int index)
    {
        if ((object)arg == null)
            return (T)(object)Convert.ToInt32(item[index]);//throws specified cast not valid

        if (arg.GetType() == typeof(int))
            return (T)(object)Convert.ToInt32(item[index]);

        if (arg.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return (T)(object)arg.ToString();

        if (arg.GetType() == typeof(decimal))
            return (T)(object)Convert.ToDecimal(item[index]);

        return default(T);
    }
```

The problem is that when I pass in `arg` as System.String or System.Nullable, they are both null. And so I get a `specified cast invalid` when I do a `Convert.ToInt32(item[index])` on a string and a `arg.ToString()` on a nullable int

Comment: When only `int`, `string` and `decimal` are possible types, you shouldn´t use generics at all, as those types don´t have *anything* in common. Instead use three methods.

Comment: Can't you just return null if the arguement is null?

Comment: This function really doesn't make any sense. If you pass in type `string` you just return `arg`, but if it's a `decimal` you return an item from the list.

Comment: Also consider using a `switch` statement when you have several similar `if (/else)` blocks.

Comment: @Mithgroth I can return null but the property I am assigning it to does not accept null values

Comment: This is really not how you should be using generics

Comment: You are using generics when you have no use of generics for such a function. Use `(Type type)` instead of generics

Comment: Instead of comaring the type of the `arg`-parameter simply check it the argument *is an instance of the type* using the `is`-operator: `if(arg is string) ...`.

Comment: For what is the `arg` parameter at all? If the method is generic you have `T` and know it's type. Also, don't pass the list and the index but only a single `string item`,

Comment: What *is* the content of `item` with the provided `index` when `arg` is `null`?

Comment: You need to take a step back and reconsider what you are trying to do. Because your function doesn't make any sense as it stands. How are you using this code? To do what? You are trying to convert a string in `item` to some other type, but what is `arg` supposed to be? You say *" the property I am assigning it to does not accept null values"*, but `default(T)` is going to return null when `T` is `string` or a `nullable`, so it's unclear what you expect to have happen in those cases. And what property are you assigning to that'll accept an `int` or a `string` but not `null`?

Answer (score 3):

Don´t use generics when only a few *unrelated* types are possible, that don´t have anything in common. `string`, `int` and `decimal` are completely different types, there´s nothing common you could do with them (except calling their `ToString`-method and some others inherited from `object`).

Instead use three different methods:

```
protected decimal GetDecimal(decimal arg) { ...}
protected string GetString(string arg) { ...}
protected int GetInt(int arg) { ...}
```

This way you can even omit the `arg`-parameter at all, which seems to exist only as dummy-instance of the correct type to make a generic work. Thus you have to know the correct type at compile-time anyway, so you can also provide it directly by chosing the correct method.

If you really *have* to use generics, use the `is`-operator:

```
protected T GetValue<T>(T arg, List<string> item, int index)
{
    if (arg is int)
        return (T)(object)Convert.ToInt32(item[index]);

    if (arg is string)
        return (T)(object)arg.ToString();

    if (arg is decimal)
        return (T)(object)Convert.ToDecimal(item[index]);

    return default(T);
}
```

However that´s not what generics are made for.

Comment: They want to support nullable int/decimal values, given the title of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your method shouldn't be generic at all. This is what overloads are for:

```
protected object GetValue(
    object arg, List<string> item, int index)
{
    if (arg == null)
        //...
    else
        //whatever seems fit for an object that isn't resolved to
        //another overload
}

protected string GetValue(
    string arg, List<string> item, int index)
{
     return arg; //hmmm, how useful is this?
}

protected decimal GetValue(
     decimal arg, List<string> item, int index)
{
     return Convert.ToDecimal(item[index]);
}

protected int GetValue(
    int arg, List<string> item, int index)
{
     return Convert.ToInt32(item[index]);
}
```

That works much better. Don't use generics when the valid types are a *finite set*. Generics should work for any type `T` that complies with certain constaints.

In general, if you start needing runtime type checks in a generic method, you are doing something wrong!

UPDATE: Following Servy's commentary, if you need support for nullable ints, decimals, etc. then simply write the corresponding overloads. I'd like to point out however that in the following scenario:

```
int? i = null;
var result = GetValue((object)i);
```

It is not possible to discern inside `GetValue` if the argument `arg` was really a `string`, a nullable value type or an object. `null` has no type information you can leverage aside from knowing that the argument is statically typed `object`.

This, obviously, is very different:

```
protected int? GetValue(int? arg, List<string> item, int index) { ... }

int? i = null;
var result = GetValue(i);
```

Here `arg` is also `null` but the resolved overload is `GetValue(int? arg)`, therefore you *know* that `arg` is a nullable `int`.

Comment: They want to support nullable int/decimal values, given the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I couldn't make sense of the code you've posted, but I tried my best to give you a working solution.

In essense, instead of misusing generics like that, why don't you box the object in the list and then call the method with a type parameter.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
protected T GetValue<T>(List<object> item, int index) {
    if (index > item.Count || item[index] is default)
        throw new ArgumentException("Very detailed message");
    else if (item[index] is T val)
        return val;
    else
        return (T)item[index]; // Will stil throw an exception if cast fails
        // Of course you can add different/more checks
}
```